# control visibility of Telerki GridViewDataColumn through IsVisibility

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, telerik-grid

I want to show/hide a `DataGridViewColumn` dynamically, so I have created a `bool` property named IsColumnVisible in my presentation model and applied it to `Visibility=IsColumnVisible` in xaml.

tried this also,

```xml
<conv:VisibilityToBoolConverter x:Key="VisibleIfTrue"
                                Inverted="True"
                                Not="False" />
<conv:VisibilityToBoolConverter x:Key="VisibleIfFalse"
                                Inverted="True"
                                Not="True" />
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="100"
                            Header="Deadline Date"
                            DataFormatString="{}{0:MM/dd}"
                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding DEADLINE_DT}"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            TextAlignment="Center"
                            HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}"
                            ShowFieldFilters="False"
                            IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsDeadlineDateVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfTrue}}" />
```

and this is my property in code behind (Presentation model)

```
public bool IsDeadlineDateVisible
{
    get
    {
        return _IsDeadlineDateVisible;
    }
    set
    {
        _IsDeadlineDateVisible = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsDeadlineDateVisible");
    }
}
```

Its not working (column remains always visible). Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a VisibilityToBoolConverter since IsVisible is of type bool and the property you are using for binding "IsDeadlineDateVisible" is a bool as well.
Hence, you can directly use as follows:
IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsDeadlineDateVisible}", without a converter.

The converter would be required if the dependency property you are binding to, is of type Visibility, for example, for a Grid, the dependency property Visibility is not a bool.
To toggle the visibility of a grid, you would require a converter that you have used above.

Comment: The `IsVisble` property not working with binding